# Output author and description if description is not empty

Tags: author

Is it possible to only display the author's name and description (aka bio) *if* the description contains text?

This code doesn't work (it doesn't return the name or description) but hopefully it can be edited to accomplish this goal:

```
<?php
$authorDesc = the_author_meta($post->ID, 'description', true);
if (!empty($authorDesc)) {
?>
<em>by <?php the_author(); ?></em>
<span><?php the_author_meta('description'); ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$authordesc = get_the_author_meta( 'description' );

if ( ! empty ( $authordesc ) )
{
?>
    <a href="<?php
    echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'id' ) );
    ?>"><?php
    the_author();
    ?></a>
    <?php
    echo wpautop( $authordesc );
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to use `get_the_author_meta` instead of `the_autho_meta` to give a vakue to `$authorDesc` (`get_the_author_meta` returns the value, `the_author_meta` displays it).

Secondly, you need to use `user_description` as the argument for both functions instead of `description`.

Hope it works.

EDIT - [Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta) is the documentation to `the_author_meta` for more info.
EDIT 2 - You also don't need to declare $post->ID as the first parameter for `the_author_meta`. Are you using it inside the loop?

Comment: Yes, I'm using this inside the loop. I tried your edits but can't seem to get it working: *<?php
$authorDesc = get_the_author_meta('','user_description', true);
if (!empty($authorDesc)) {
?>
<em>by <?php the_author(); ?></em>
<span><?php get_the_author_meta('user_description'); ?></span>
<?php } ?>*

Comment: @Ryan - Forgot to mention, try to use `get_the_author_meta=("user_description")`,without `true`. And, in the second run,in the span, you need to either `echo get_the_user_meta` or use `the_author_meta` (no get).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (10 years later lol)

```
<?php // Get author's bio
$user_description = get_the_author_meta( 'user_description', $post->post_author ); ?>
    
<?php if ( ! empty( $user_description ) ): ?>
<p class="author-desc"> 
<?php the_author_meta('description') ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: May as well use that ``$user_description` variable you've filled with the description on line 2 rather than making another query with `the_author_meta()` function. Remember to escape output or apply filters though :-)